# Unable to volume down songs in music player after GDR2 update

Tags: 8.0, lumia, volume

Recently I bought lumia 625, and i have added some songs to SDcard (before GDR2 update). After few days I got update for GDR2 and updated. After updating I downloaded some songs from store, and then when I play this songs in `Music+Videos` app while playing song I am unable to down the volume of player.

Comment: This is not related to GDR-2 update, as I faced same problem with GDR-1 and GDR-2. And still facing with GDR-3 too. I suspect WhatsApp(Not sure) for these issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are some songs in my library too which are not responding to the volume command, but not all. I think this is a bug related to nokia music because 99% of those songs are from nokia music. I think you should cut that song to your computer and paste it back. Otherwise you should simply delete that song and download it from some other source.